# C# Set Receive timeout (best/sufficient time)

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, websocket

I want to know what is the best time of Receive/Send Timeout

```
tcpSocket.ExclusiveAddressUse = true;
tcpSocket.LingerState = new LingerOption (true, 10);
tcpSocket.NoDelay = true;
tcpSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
tcpSocket.SendTimeout = 5000;
tcpSocket.Ttl = 42;
Console.WriteLine("Tcp Socket configured:");
```

I am using 5 seconds but i feel its high.. in .net example they set 1 seconds so

Comment: This really depends on what you are trying to achieve, there is no happy middle.

Comment: There is no *best time*, it depends on your application and the network.

Comment: yes in general what time is sufficient i want to know that only in general

Comment: In general anywhere between a few milliseconds to 30 seconds.

Comment: But there may be exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to msdn the timeouts are defined as following :

```
Receive Timeout :Gets or sets the interval of time that a connection can remain inactive, during which no application messages are received, before it is dropped.
Send Timeout : Gets or sets the interval of time provided for a write operation to complete before the transport raises an exception.
```

I would leave the receive timeout as the default (infinite) so when you have an idle channel the connection will not close.  Unless you have the keep-alive running which periodically send a message with zero bytes.

The send timeout you have to be careful of setting the value too low.  TCP is reliable meaning every datagram gets an ack.  When an ack is not sent another datagram is sent up to 3 retries normally.

What happens with TCP when a channel is slow retries start occurring which sends additional repeat datagrams which then slows the channel even more until there are so many retries that no data gets through.

Also when the receive end of a connection is running slow the acks may not get sent back immediately.  So you have to allow the receive end time to issue the ack.  Usually the ack is done automatically by the network card and shouldn't be an issue.

Also you have to consider if there are virus checkers or firewalls that are intercepting the messages.

Comment: Does this apply when doing async send and async receive?         `_tcpClient.Client.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, BufferSize, 0, AsyncSocketReadCallbak, this);`

Comment: See the MSDN example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples